# How do I pass the main window's handle to a new thread using win32 API only?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have read that I need to have the HWND placed on the heap. Is that correct?

I need this to read values from user input.

Thank you in advance!

```
VOID MakeThread(HWND hWnd)
{

    HWND* h = new HWND(hWnd);
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, WorkerThread, h, 0, nullptr);

    if (hThread != nullptr) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    delete h;
}

unsigned int __stdcall WorkerThread(VOID* h)
{
char num[71] = { 0 };
GetDlgItemTextA((*(HWND*)h), 2001, num, 70);

//Get number from edit box 2001
//Do work with the above-mentioned number

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I have read that I need to have the HWND placed on the heap" what can that means? where did you read that?

Comment: This is screaming [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) all over the place. Answering the literal question: A `HWND` is a value that you can pass as is to your thread procedure. Doing so doesn't make much sense, and the way you're using it is entirely unsafe. Accessing a window from a thread other than the one that created it requires synchronization (which you aren't providing). It all reads as though you believe that this were a solution to your problem, because you haven't yet understood how input works in Windows.

Comment: This also implements an alarmingly common anti-pattern: Creating a thread followed by a **synchronous** wait on the thread. You could simply not create the thread altogether: The behavior would be identical. You should seriously consider understanding the Windows API first. Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is standard learning material.

Comment: @IInspectable Synchronization is being done by SendMessage, so this code is okay at least from a synchronization perspective. However, it does deadlock because the new thread is sending a message to the original thread, which cannot receive the message because it is waiting for the new thread to exit.

Comment: @ray My previous comment was referring to dereferencing `h`, which just happens to be safe due to the infinite synchronous wait (which, as you note, causes a deadlock). The note on synchronization was meant to promote safe code, even if not completely accurate. There is *some* level of synchronization provided by the window manager. I'll leave it to you to [write about the lesser known subtleties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051010-09/?p=33843).

Answer (score 2):

> *I have read that I need to have the HWND placed on the heap. Is that correct?*

Not really. Assuming that the `HWND` remains valid for the duration of the created thread (if it is the application's main window, then that is a reasonable assumption), **and** that the `MakeThread` function will not return until that thread is finished (as is the case in your code), then you can just give the address of its `HWND hWnd` argument as the `arglist` parameter in the call to `_beginthreadex`.

You don't have to create a copy of that window handle on the heap. Here's a simplified version of your `MakeThread` function:

```cpp
VOID MakeThread(HWND hWnd)
{
    stringstream stream;
    stream << &hWnd << "\n" << hWnd;
    std::string s = stream.str();
    MessageBoxA(hWnd, s.c_str(), "Caller: hWnd?", 0);
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, WorkerThread, &hWnd, 0, nullptr);
    if (hThread != nullptr) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
}
```

However, if your `MakeThread` function were to return *without* waiting for the created thread to complete, then that passed address would become invalid (at some point). But, in that scenario, you would have to make other changes to your code, so that you could keep track of the created thread handle.

Comment: I changed the code some just after you answered.

Comment: @David_M I noticed that. But your changes don't really invalidate my answer.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't just passing the `HWND` value? It's pointer-sized so it easily fits into the thread procedure's signature. With that done you can now remove the wait. Noone is relying on the address `&hWnd`, so no synchronization is required.

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm. In the OP's *original* code, the thread function was dereferencing the given pointer: `stream << (HWND)h << char(13) << char(10) << (*(HWND*)h);`, so just passing the `hWnd` object made that (and the `_beginthreadex` call) fail.

Comment: My answer simply addresses the question of whether the address passed to the thread function needs to be on the heap - which it doesn't. But your comments on the question itself are completely valid and pertinent.

Comment: Of course you have to change both sides of the contract. With multithreading, passing values is **always** preferable. It is always well defined, and never needs any sort of synchronization. Passing addresses across threads should be your last resort, only to be used if you cannot possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

An `HWND` is already a pointer type (to a global system resource). You can just pass it around as-is, there is no need to wrap it with `new` at all:

```cpp
void MakeThread(HWND hWnd)
{
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, WorkerThread, hWnd, 0, nullptr);
    if (hThread != nullptr) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
}

unsigned int __stdcall WorkerThread(void* h)
{
    char num[71] = { 0 };
    GetDlgItemTextA((HWND)h, 2001, num, 70);

    //Get number from edit box 2001
    //Do work with the above-mentioned number

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, creating a thread just to immediately wait for its termination is a complete waste of a thread. You may as well just call the target function directly instead, the end result will be exactly the same, just without the extra overhead:

```cpp
void DontMakeThread(HWND hWnd)
{
    WorkerThread(hWnd);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you use `new HWND(hWnd)`, your object will be allocated on the heap by default, not stack. Thus, you can share it across without a risk the object to be lost due the stack unwinding.

Another point is you start the thread and then wait for the completion. As a side-effect, you could use even a stack-allocated data to pass to the thread because the stack is here until the thread exit (exactly, `WaitForSingleObject` line).

And handling user input is not related to heap/stack allocation in general. Could you re-phrase your question in that part or create another question on that mean?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A `HWND` is a value, just like `42` is a value. When a variable of type `HWND` goes out of scope *nothing* happens. The lifetime of a window is not in any way tied to the lifetime of the variable that happens to store a handle to that window.

Comment: I edited my post to make my question more clear.

Comment: @IInspectable Given `HWND* h = new HWND(hWnd);` statement means we have a pointer `h`, not a value itself. So, you allocate a pointer (placing the data on a heap, unless you use custom allocators) and if you go out of the scope without releasing the pointer, you got a memory leak. So, that piece of heap memory holding your `42` value is marked as "in use" and can't be used by the app anymore.

Comment: The question is about **lifetimes**. A leaked heap allocation has infinite lifetime, so no memory safety issue will come of it. The point is that `new HWND(hWnd)` is beyond any reason. There is literally no reason, ever, to do this. It's wasted cycles, wasted memory, and nothing good will come of it. I mean, tracking a pointer to a pointer-sized object, just so that you can pass it across threads? Why not simply pass the pointer-size object then?